# Django migration error: has no field named u'DO_NOTHING'

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to add a foreign key to my models in Django 1.9 with the option `on_delete='DO_NOTHING'` per instructions on Django Docs, but for version 1.10. I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` without any problems but when I tried to run `python manage.py migrate` of course I got the error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Entrance has no field named u'DO_NOTHING'`

Realizing my mistake, I changed the option to `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` and ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` again but I'm still getting the same error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Entrance has no field named u'DO_NOTHING'`

Looks like something is wrong in migration files. Not too familiar with internal workings of Django so I don't know where to look to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Provide your model

Answer (score 0):

When you added the migration with `on_delete='DO_NOTHING'` django generated a migration. Then, you generated a new migration with `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`. So you have to delete both migrations located in `your_project/your_app/migrations/` and then execute makemigrations again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it created other problems. So I ended up what I described below.

Answer (score 0):

That should be

```
on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
```

Answer (score 0):

Look django_migrations table in db. Find last migrated migrations file there
and compare this file with next migrations file.
You can also add last migrations file in there with manually if everything okay in your database.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is going into the `my_project/myapp/migrations` directory and going through the `*.py` files and fixing the `operations` variable (below) by removing `to_field='DO_NOTHING'` item in the corresponding `field` item. Hopefully this won't create other problems.

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='cave',
        name='entrance',
        field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='listcaves.Entrance', to_field='DO_NOTHING'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='entrance',
        name='name',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True),
    ),
]
```